# How to properly login user via Django

Tags: django

I am trying to login user in Django. If I use the code below everything works fine

```
def login(request):
    return render(request, 'web/login.html')

def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if Member.objects.filter(username=request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password']).exists():
            member = Member.objects.get(username=request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password'])

            return render(request, 'web/home.html', {'member': member})
        else:
            context = {'msg': 'Invalid username or password'}
            return render(request, 'web/login.html', context)
```

Here am trying to perform the same login by processing data using **clean_data** but it gives error:

> The view webApp.views.home didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Does it mean that my form data is empty or not posted?

I have a [reference solution found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49663398/django-the-view-didnt-return-an-httpresponse-object-it-returned-none-instead) but with no luck.

Here is the code:

```
def login(request):
    return render(request, 'web/login.html')

def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = loginForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:

        if form.is_valid():
        # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            username =  form.cleaned_data['username']
            password =  form.cleaned_data['password']

            #if len(username) < 5 || len(password) < 5:

            if Member.objects.filter(username=username, password=password).exists():
                member = Member.objects.get(username=username, password=password)
                return render(request, 'web/home.html', {'member': member})
                print("success")
            else:
                context = {'msg': 'Invalid username or password'}
                return render(request, 'web/login.html', context)
                print('failed')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea of the error is, any view in Django must return **`HttpResponse`** or similar object. Here in your views, you are not returning the `HttpResponse` all the time. That is, the program execution not going into the **`if...`** clause of your code. and the execution can't go into the **`else..`** clause unless you define them. So, I've added some **`else`** conditions.

Try this

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = loginForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:

        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']

            # if len(username) < 5 || len(password) < 5:

            if Member.objects.filter(username=username, password=password).exists():
                member = Member.objects.get(username=username, password=password)
                return render(request, 'web/home.html', {'member': member})
                print("success")
            else:
                context = {'msg': 'Invalid username or password'}
                return render(request, 'web/login.html', context)
                print('failed')
        else:
            context = {'msg': 'Form is not valid'}
            return render(request, 'web/login.html', context)
    else:
        context = {'msg': 'HTTP method is not "POST"'}
        return render(request, 'web/login.html', context)
```